# Removing/hiding items in TOC panel (pie chart symbology)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, table-of-contents

I work in ArcMap 10.4. I need to find a way to remove/hide some of the items displayed in the TOC after applying Pie chart symbology to features.
The main idea is the items are somewhat duplicated but nonetheless needed for the correct display of data.
Later the layers will be published for browsing in a map app on Portal for ArcGIS environment. There I need only one set of items to be displayed (as seen in the picture).
Just to clarify - this has nothing to do with legends.

Is there a way to do it?

So basically I need to hide or remove items labelled as '_2'

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't... Go and use the field calculator to sum the pairs (vodo+voda2, ...) to avoid having double entries. That avoids separated sectors, sharing the same colors, too.

Comment: I can't do that. They are not 'doubled'. They all have different values for a feature. There are fields from, let's say, from 'A' to 'H' (primary stat) and from 'A2' to 'H2' (secondary stat). Each feature can have a combination of two values (for example 'B' and 'C2'). Those are then displayed as pie charts.

So I need to find a way for the 'symbology' in TOC to display only 'A' to 'H' values. It would be easy if it was done as a real legend but it won't. It will be displayed as a layer in Webmap Application in Portal for ArcGIS...

Comment: Hm, as a cartographer i would argue, that a pie chart is not the appropriate symbolization, but we know that GIS (incl. ArcGIS) is somehow limited in the field of thematic maps.

Comment: I totally agree it's not the best method to use. I enclosed a pic of some of the features symbolized using the fields. Would you maybe recommend a better method to display those data? Each feature contains either one or two values.